# Get XML values from XML database string in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

I’m trying to get the values of an xml snippet that is stored in my database but can’t seem to make it work.  They are all coming back null...  The xml looks like this:

```
<fields>
<field id="EmployeeID">1002240002</field>
<field id="JobType">Web Manager</field>
<field id="CompanyCode">R6297C</field>
</fields>
```

My Code, with the string from the database is below.

```
string xml = "<fields><field id=\"EmployeeID\">1002240002</field><field id=\"JobType\">Web Manager</field><field id=\"CompanyCode\"> R6297C </field></fields>";

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

var n = xmlDoc.GetElementById("EmployeeID ");

                if (n != null)
                { 
                    var employeeId = xmlDoc.GetElementById("EmployeeID ").InnerText;
                }
```

Any help on this?  I know I am missing something easy here...  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following XPath query

```
string xpath = "field[@id='EmployeeID']";
XmlNode fieldNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
var id = Int32.Parse(fieldNode.InnerText);
```

Or Linq to Xml

```
var id = (from f in xdoc.Descendants()
          where (string)f.Attribute("id") == "EmployeeID"
          select (int)f).Single();
```

Or with fluent interface

```
var id = xdoc.Descendants()
             .Where(f => (string)f.Attribute("id") == "EmployeeID")
             .Select(f => (int)f)
             .Single();
```

*BTW* xdoc is an instance of `XDocument` class:

```
var xdoc = new XDocument(xml);
```

Comment: I would recommend to use the `XPathReader` as `XmlDocument` has a performance penalty.